# SQL Server Management Studio: See Object Explorer Details for objects in this folder

Tags: ssms

I am working with a database hosted at GoDaddy using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (version 10, for SQL Server 2008).

I am getting this message:
See Object Explorer Details for objects in this folder
[image]

probably because they have more than 2500 databases there.

I can still access everything from the Object Explorer Details, but it's a pain when you have to do it everyday.

Does anyone know any way to get the database I am working on to appear in the Object Explorer on the left?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a database admin, not a programming questions. There is a dedicated database admin Stackexchange site.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It looks like this is a bug in SQL Server Mangement Studio.

[From Microsoft](http://connect.microsoft.com/sql/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=362453)...

> The current limitation of 2500 items
>   expanded in one Object Explorer Node
>   has been put in place to prevent the
>   Tree View Control from exceeding the
>   64K limit when multiple Object
>   Explorer nodes get expanded. The
>   Windows XP and Windows Server 2003
>   version of the Tree View control has a
>   bug where it just stops displaying
>   nodes once the total number of nodes
>   exceeds 64K.
>
> Object Explorer Details window can be
>   used to see the entire list of items -
>   it doesn't have the above limitation.
>   Users can see the list by clicking at
>   the informational node that displays
>   the warning in the Object Explorer.
>   Object Explorer Details duplicates
>   most of Object Explorer functionality
>   including all the context menus.
>
> We are reviewing the customer feedback
>   and considering adjusting this
>   behavior one more time. Please let us
>   know if you'd prefer the old behavior
>   back or if you have any other
>   suggestions.

I am having this problem on a Windows 7 Machine, so I do not think it is just limited to Windows XP and Windows Server 2003 as Microsoft says.

Comment: Yep, Windows 7 with sql server 2008 R2 on a machine is showing me this.  Below I see that hitting F7 key does indeed allow for a quick fix workaround.

Answer (score 12):

here is how you fix that, you either press F7 key to display the object explorer details, or from view > Object explorer details

then select your database from the list of databases which will appear in the object explorer details window.

Answer (score 0):

I'd also suggest the filter option in the table context menu, since the question explicitly asked how to avoid the Object Explorer Details.