# sql server Stored Procedures folder is empty

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm having an issue with my sql management studio 2008 R2 install. My company has hundreds of stored procedures in the `[database name]->Programmability->Stored Procedures` directory; however, nothing is appearing on my computer.  I've verified that my user has access to the folder, and it's contents, by authenticating and viewing the folder contents on another computer--and all the stored procedures appear as desired.

I'm not sure where the problem could be coming from by the only things that currently appear in the Stored Procedures folder are:

```
 System Stored Procedures
 See Object Explorer Details for objects in this folder
```

However, when I double click (or even right click) on the second option, nothing happens.  Has anyone ran into this issue before?

Comment: Some filter applied?

Comment: No filter, just checked.  And cleared just incase.

Comment: did you check on another computer with your user?

Comment: @Paolo yes, I mentioned that in my OP

Comment: Did you try to reset you managment studio options? Also, do a `Select * from sys.tables` or `select * from sysobjects where xtype = 'u'` and/or ask for the dba to do a database profile to try to figure where the problem might be.

Comment: Update, if I select "View->Object Explorer Details" the stored procedures will show up, but in a results pane and not in the Object Explorer window.  I began searching through the view and management studio options to find a way to change this but could not find anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this is a known bug in `Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio v.10.00` to resolve, you can upgrade to v10.10 or anything above 2008.  Note, 2012 and 2014 management studios are still compatible with 2008 R2 servers.

Here is the link to the other SO question I found related to this issue which led to the Microsoft bug post:

[SQL Server Management Studio: See Object Explorer Details for objects in this folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614690/sql-server-management-studio-see-object-explorer-details-for-objects-in-this-fo)

Comment: Do you have a link to the bug? KB article or Connect item?

Answer (score 1):

for fix it, we have to press F7 key to display the object explorer details, or from view  Object explorer details

then select your database from the list of databases which will appear in the object explorer details window.